# using perl to get users of AD group

Tags: perl, active-directory

I've been trying to get this to print out all the members in "domain users".  Problem is, it only prints out a small portion of them, then it just sorta stops.  Not sure why.  Can someone shed some light on the problem?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

 use Net::LDAP;

 my $uid = "cn=account,cn=users,dc=domain,dc=local";
 my $bindPass = "password";
 my $ldapServer = "ldap://server.domain.local";

 # connect to ldap server
 $ldap = Net::LDAP -> new ($ldapServer) || die "Could not connect to server\n";

 # bind to ldap server
 $ldap -> bind($uid, password => $bindPass);

 # search for group
 $mesg = $ldap -> search(filter => "(&(cn=Domain Users))", base => "dc=domain,dc=local");

 $entry = $mesg -> entry;
# @members = $entry -> get_value ('member;Range=0-*');
 #the above entry when uncommented doesn't work either.
@members = $entry -> get_value ('member');

 foreach $thing (@members) {
   print "$thing\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Net::LDAP](http://search.cpan.org/~marschap/perl-ldap-0.58/lib/Net/LDAP.pod) docs:

> sizelimit => N
>
> ```
> A sizelimit that restricts the maximum number of entries to be 
> returned as a result of the search. A value of 0, and the default,
> means that no restriction is requested. Servers may enforce a maximum
> number of entries to return.
> ```

It might very well be your AD server has a restriction configured. Try checking `$mesg->error()` after the search.

You might have more success if you use `ldap://server.domain.local:3268/` as your URL. AD uses a "mini" ldap server on that port to talk to replicated servers (google "global catalog"); you won't see all attributes on that server, but maybe it's less restrictive as to the maximum number of entries.

Comment: That looked promising, but ultimately neither worked.  Thinking about the AD possibility.  We're on a 2008 domain.  I'll also try researching whether the bottleneck is with the servers and if so, how to change.